# Why do I Have 800 pixels in PAL video line

Tags: stm32, video, decoder

I have a DCMI peripheral (STM32H7)  that receives video data from TVP5150 with discrete VSYNC/HSYNC.

I have 306 (it should be 305, but there is a chance that this is because of the way I count number of interrupts) active video full line interrupts in one frame, with one line duration of 64 us.
It's all sounds good but it's seems that I have 800 Y values received during one line (monochrome video).

That's seems odd to me,  Is there any explanation why it is that way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what you get when you capture everything except for the HSYNC pulse itself using a standard 13.5 MHz sample rate — back porch (5.7 µs = 77 pixels) + active video (700 pixels) + front porch (1.65 µs = 23 pixels) = 800 pixels total.

The HSYNC pulse is 4.7 µs = 64 pixels, giving you the total of 864 pixels for the line period.

Comment: Thank you so much! Do I understand correctly that this is bt601 standart? What type of documentation describe what pixels I should use to draw a picture? Or is it as simple as you say just use pixels from 77 pixel to 800-23?

Comment: That does not add up. It's 720 pixels active, so the blank area is 144 pixels.

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you have set the video decoder to output HSYNC; but have set the STM32H7 to expect HACTIVE, so it samples everything but the sync. By default TVP5150 HSYNC pulse is 64 pixels or 128 clocks, so 864-64 is 800, and you are left with 800 pixels per line, so it contains back porch and front porch blanking too instead of just the 720 pixels you really want.

Comment: What pixels in this 800 pixels line are video pixels, what standard describe it? Where I can get the information how I should draw this pixels?

Comment: The TVP5150 datasheet will tell you what it outputs. It is another matter if it conforms to a standard or not, but the relevant standard is ITU-R BT.601. The Y pixels are the grayscale luminance. Cb and Cr must be upsampled and YCbCr converted to RGB if you want to display a color picture.